# JWT signature for web push using PHP

Tags: php, jwt, web-push, vapid

I'm trying to send web push notifications using PHP. I have read about how to implement the web push protocol, for instance [here](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/web-push-protocol/). However, I think I don't really get the step where the author of this guide explains how to form the Authorization header. Using [this](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.3/README.md) library and given my VAPID keys created by an [online generator](https://vapidkeys.com/), I tried the following:

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Ecdsa\Sha256;

$signer = new Sha256();
$privateKey = new Key('<the generated private VAPID key>');
$time = time();

$token = (new Builder())->permittedFor('https://example.com')
                        ->expiresAt($time + 3600)
                        ->withHeader('alg', 'ES256')
                        ->withClaim('sub', 'mailto:someone@example.com')
                        ->getToken($signer, $privateKey);
```

What I'd like to get is something similar to `<JWT Info>.<JWT Data>.<Signature>` out of `$token`. However, I get an Error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: It was not possible to parse your key, reason: error:0909006C:PEM ...

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't know what a VAPID key is, but your `$signer` works with ECDSA keys. Given what i got using your provided VAPID generator, I'm pretty sure this is not an ECDSA key.

Comment: In the [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8292#section-2), it says in section 2 that these keys _MUST be usable with the Elliptic
   Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) over the P-256 curve_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, the `Lcobucci/jwt` API [uses both](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/ebb24870d4f42bd7020f87fa728f34ffa751e07c/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php#L47) `openssl_pkey_get_private()` and `openssl_pkey_get_public()` functions.

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php), they expect PEM-encoded keys, and this is not what you supplied. Those kind of keys starts with a *-------BEGIN* prefix.

Comment: That's exactly right. The online generator gives us the "final version" of the key, which can be used with the most popular Node.js modules. We can create both a .pem file and VAPID keys in plain text files using the openssl commands I discovered [here](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php#authentication-vapid).